# Twitter Boostrap : modal window not playing video after reopning the modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have 5 links that opens 5 different videos in the modal window,
 the following code  plays the video in the modal window and stops the video when the modal window is closed.

But, when i try open the same video again the video is disabled in the modal window and no longer playable. Is there a fix for this?

here is modal window code  and javascript and fiddle link below

[MY FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/s2f0jrzc/7/)

Modal

```
<div class="modal fade video2 advSearchModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Video 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="bs-example" data-example-id="responsive-embed-16by9-iframe-youtube">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">

              <video class="embed-responsive-item" controls src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" type="video/mp4"> </video>

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".advSearchModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function(evt) {
      var player = $(evt.target).find('video'),
        vidSrc = player.prop('src');
      player.prop('src', ''); // to force it to pause
      player.prop('src', vidSrc);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the following trick to stop HTML5 video. pause() the video on modal close and set currentTime = 0;

```
$(".advSearchModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function(evt) {
  $(evt.target).find('video').get(0).pause();
  $(evt.target).find('video').get(0).currentTime = 0; 
});
```

Set `currentTime = 0` for when you open modal the video play of the begin.